# This Infinite Random Sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recursion

I was working on Random sequence and LCG's when I found this recursive algorithm:

> $$X_{n+1}=[{\sqrt{n(X_n+1)}}]\%10$$

Where, $[x]$ is the floor function.

When executed with $X_0=0$, the sequence turns out to be:

> 0,0,1,2,5,9,5,4,5,9,8,0,1,6,4,1,1,2,9,6,0,0,1,1,2,1,5,3,4,2,0,0,1,5,0,4,8,8,1,3,8,0,1,9,5,7,7,0,7........

I tested it and found out that there is no repition in this sequence till $X_{10000}$
Is it a better alternative to LCG's?

Comment: A quick test reveals that the mean of your sequence deviates significantly from $4.5$ (I stopped watching after $200\times 10^6$ numbers $X_n,$ finally  the mean values is about $4.19\dots 4.21.$  What are your values?

Comment: i also got values around $4.405702381885952 $ at $10^8$ numbers

Comment: Also I get another sequence: $0,0,1,2,3\dots$. $x_4$ is not $5$ because
$x_4 = [\sqrt{3(2+1)}] \% 10 = 3$

Comment: Better in what sense? It isn't clear what you're asking.